# Webpack is including all JSON files in my bundle

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, webpack, build

I'm having a security issue that my webpack is creating a `bundle.js` with all environment variables I got in my code.

But I set a NODE_ENV when I run the build script and conditionally load the script I want. So for production I should only load the variables in `production.json`. The same for testing and development.

When I open my `build.js` all the variable in all the environment files are there.

What could be the problem?

**config.js**

```
...
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const envConfig = require(`./env/${env}.json`);
config[env] = envConfig;
...
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
{
    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle." + process.env.NODE_ENV + ".js",
        path: path.resolve("dist")
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/, /src\/env\/*.json/],
                use: ["babel-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: { extensions: [".js", ".jsx"] }
}
```

I want only one object of environment variables to be in the `build.js` and ignore all the others.